# Api "show" returns "null" json on api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am writing an api controller for my rails project. When I call api/orders, I get the full list of orders in my project in a json. However, when I call for a *single* order, the json returns "null", even though my record is there.

controllers/api/orders_controller.rb

```
class Api::OrdersController < Api::BaseController
before_action :doorkeeper_authorize! # equivalent of authenticate_user!

# GET /orders
# GET /orders.json
def index
  @orders = Order.all
  render json: @orders
end

# GET /orders/1
# GET /orders/1.json
def show
  render json: @order
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_order
  @order = Order.find(params[:id])
end

def current_resource_owner
  User.find(doorkeeper_token.resource_owner_id) if doorkeeper_token
end
end
```

/api/orders/2?access_token=[Token]

```
null
```

rails console output

```
Order.find(2)
Order Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Order id: 2, invoice: "TEST", description: "Test continuity", weight: 100.0, length: 100, width: 100, height: 100, account_id: 1, driver_id: 2, state: "waiting_pickup", account_quote: 729, driver_quote: 547, created_at: "2017-10-19 04:35:58", updated_at: "2017-10-19 04:37:17", driver_rating: 5, account_rating: 5, guid: "7e77f2e7-cc11-440f-8871-1ce3349b61d9">
```

routes.rb

```
namespace :api do
resources :orders
end
```

Comment: Can u show orders.json.jbuilder and _order.json.jbuilder

Answer (score 0):

In your `show` action, `@order` is `null` and hence it's showing so in api response. You need to set the value of `@order` variable before rendering it. Modify the `show` method as below to make it work:

```
# GET /orders/1
# GET /orders/1.json
def show
  set_order
  render json: @order
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a [before_action](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-before_action) with `set_order` method being called.  `before_action` approach will also help you to reuse it if you plan a `update` method in future.

```
class Api::OrdersController < Api::BaseController

  before_action :set_order, only: [:show]

  # GET /orders/1
  # GET /orders/1.json
  def show
     render json: @order
  end 

  private

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_order
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def show
  @order  = Order.find(params[:id])
  render json: @order
end
```